# Choices for Integrationg by Parts

Tags: calculus, integration, exponentiation

I am working on an integration by parts problem, and, it looks like I got something incorrect somewhere. I have been told to follow LIATE (**L** ogarithmic, **I** nverse trigonometric, **A** lgebraic, **T** rigonometric, **E** xponential)  when making a choice for selecting the `u` term in integration by parts. So, here is where I start:

> Find $\displaystyle \int \frac{x \cdot e^{2x}}{{\left(2x + 1\right)}^{2}}$
>
> $u = {(2x + 1)}^{2} = 4x^2 + 4x + 1$
>
> $du = 16x + 4 \ dx$
>
> $v = \frac{x}{2} \cdot e^{2x}$
>
> $dv = x \cdot e^{2x} \ dx$
>
> ... and the rest of the problem is solved in this manner.

In the end I come up with:

> ${\left(2x + 1\right)}^{2} \cdot \frac{x}{2} \cdot e^{2x} - \left(4x^2 + x\right)\left(e^{2x}\right) + \left(16x + 1\right)\left(\frac{1}{2} \cdot e^{2x}\right) - {8e}^{2x} \ dx$

Comparing my answer with that from the student solutions handbook, here is how they start:

> Find $\displaystyle \int \frac{x \cdot e^{2x}}{{\left(2x + 1\right)}^{2}}$
>
> $u = x \cdot e^{2x}$
>
> $du = x \cdot 2e^{2x} + e^{2x} \ dx = e^{2x} \left(2x + 1\right) \ dx$
>
> $v = -\frac{1}{2\left(2x + 1\right)}$
>
> $dv = \frac{1}{{\left(2x + 1\right)}^{2}} \ dx$
>
> ... and the rest of the problem is solved in this manner.

In the end, they come up with:

> $$\frac{e^{2x}}{4\left(2x + 1\right)} + C$$

The answer they came up with appears to be the case since they chose their `u` term differently than I did. I purposefully didn't make the choice they did, since it was an exponential function, which I was taught should be the last choice for `u`. I chose the algebraic function.

There must be something that I am missing. Could some one please show me as to where I went wrong, and perhaps some rules that would help me make better choices for my `u` term in the future?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: In general, try to pick $u$ to be a function that has a simple derivative and $dv$ to be a function that has a simple integral.

Comment: Your calculation has errors. It should be $du=(8x+4)dx$. You had $16x+4$. You chose $dv=xe^{2x}$. But then $v$ is not what you say it is. You can check that by differentiating. The "rules" are not universal. Because of the very specific choice of $e^{2x}$, the derivative of $xe^{2x}$ happens to be $(2x+1)e^{2x}$, so there is miraculous cancellation.  General rules can't take care of all very contrived special cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for integration by parts is $\int udv=uv-\int vdu.$  You have $\int\frac{dv}u,$ which won't work.

Comment: Thank Mike, but I did use `v` and `du` in the integral. Since I used integration by parts twice, maybe that is why it looks as though I had done that.

Comment: @spryno724 What do you mean it looks like you did that?  You selected a u that was in the denominator.  Look at your choice of u and dv.  $\int udv$ would be $\int(2x+1)^2xe^{2x}dx$, which was not what you started with...

Comment: Errummm.... that was silly mistake. Ok, that was my problem! Thank you for pointing that out Mike! How could I have missed that?

Answer (score 1):

There's no hard-and-fast rule for integration by parts, much like the rest of integration. You have to (unfortunately =P ) apply your mental facilities here as well.

Over here, choice of $u$ eliminated a part of the denominator. A definite plus. Again, there's no rule for this, you've got to learn to perceive the hidden things like this.

Comment: If that is the case, then shouldn't the answer come out the be the same, regardless of what (within reason) I pick?

Comment: @spryno724 Integration is not like algebra. There are multiple methods of simplification, but only a few will work for a given problem. You must pass through certain 'gates' to reach it

Comment: Wait, is your first answer the final answer or the resultant integrand? I sort of assumed the latter as it has a dx. If not, you've made a mistake somewhere. I thought you were asking why you get something easy to integrate with one substitution, and hard with the other

Comment: Your mistake is that your u was in the denominator. $\frac{x}{(2x+1)^2}$ makes more sense as u by LIATE.

Comment: Hmmm... would $\frac{1}{{\left(2x + 1\right)}^{2}}$ have worked as `u` and $x \cdot e^{2x} \ dx$ as `dv`?

Comment: @spryno724 possibly. No guarantee that you'll reach an answer, though.